# Is it possible to strikeout a whole equation or paragraph?

Tags: equations, ulem, strikeout, cancel

I have a document in which I want to strikeout whole paragraphs including all `equation` and `eqnarray` environments. Available options such as `sout` (from `ulem`) works on paragraph but not in equations. Also `cancel` (from `cancel`) work only inside math, but not in paragraphs and in `eqnarray`s only one line at a time.

Is there a package or command that will allow to strikeout with, for example:

```
\strike{
%long paragraph or equation or eqnarray
}
```

Preferably I need a diagonal strikeout but any alternative would work.
Here it is an example:

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
  \usepackage{cancel}

  \begin{document}
  par

  \begin{eqnarray}
  %\cancel{ %cancel doesn't work for eqnarray
  f(x) & = & \sin(x) \\
  g(x) & = & \cos(x)
  %}
  \end{equation}

  par

  \end{document}
```

Comment: Off-topic:`eqnarray` is too old, actually. Use `align` or something similar (I don't know, whether `\cancel` would work with `align` -- I doubt). You are aware that your `eqnarray` env. ends with `equation`? ;-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`cancel` works with `aligned` environment, but in this case the equation numbers are lost.

```
\documentclass[]{revtex4}
  \usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,amsthm,amssymb}
  \usepackage{cancel}
%  \usepackage{ulem}

  \begin{document}

    \[%
    \cancel{%
      \begin{aligned}
        f(x) &=  \sin(x) \\
        g(x) &=  \cos(x)
      \end{aligned}
    }%
    \]


  \end{document}
```

Comment: It is funny the author of the `cancel` package https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cancel?lang=en says "Drawing slashes through
math to indicate “cancellation” is poor design. *I don’t recommend that you use this package at all.*" (emphasis mine). However I want it for "corrections".