# How to strikeout an flalign block?

Tags: cancel, strikeout

I am trying to strikeout an entire `flalign` block.  [This post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/248542/161861) shows how to strikeout an aligned block using the `cancel` package, but I'm not able to get it to work for the flalign environment.  Any ideas how to get this to work without using `tikz`?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \cancel{
        \begin{aligned}
        f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
        g(x) &= \cos(x)
    \end{aligned}
}
\end{equation*}
I want to strikeout this:
\begin{flalign*}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) && \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x) &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily define a left-aligned `equation` environment and then use the method with the nested `aligned`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/148854
\makeatletter

\newenvironment{flequation}
  {\@fleqntrue\begin{equation}}
  {\end{equation}\@fleqnfalse}
\newenvironment{flequation*}
  {\@fleqntrue\begin{equation*}}
  {\end{equation*}\@fleqnfalse}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

Some text
\begin{flequation*}
  \cancel{
    \begin{aligned}
      f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
      g(x) &= \cos(x)
    \end{aligned}
  }
\end{flequation*}
More text

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: @marmot Why?  Your post is not wrong.  Or are you thinking of [this](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/7600)?

Comment: No, I really think your answer is better. And no, I did not think of this. The purpose of this site is to provide users with very good solutions, and mine is clearly worse than yours, so there is no reason to keep it.

Comment: @marmot I ended up using the minipage solution.  I don't have a good reason, but I don't care for `\makeatletter`. 

@HenriMenke The post on beginners accepting poor answer choices was interesting.  I have been writing LaTeX for a while, but I feel that there is so much I don't know.  I was looking something up in Lamport's LaTeX book a while back, and was surprised to find that I have not been using periods correctly in some situations.

Comment: @Jeff I undeleted my answer but think that you should *not* accept it since Henri's solution is probably better for the majority of users.

Comment: @Jeff Do I understand this correctly, that you didn't use my answer because it has `\makeatletter`?  If this is such a blocker for you, I can rewrite my answer without it.

Comment: @HenriMenke I accepted your answer as correct.  I agree with @marmot that it is probably the better way to get the strikeout.  However, I try to avoid custom environments and/or using `makeatletter`.  It's just a personal preference, and I can't really give good reason why.

Comment: @Jeff You are right in the sense that the `@` is really meant to prevent random users from overwriting important macros. But as Henri stressed this is not essential for his proposal. What I do not like about my resurrected minipage answer is that one has to specify the width. I am actually a bit less concerned about the page breaks since you most likely won't cross out some equation block that goes over more than one pages.

Comment: @Jeff “I try to avoid custom environments”  What's the point of that other than making your life hard and littering your document with repeated markup instructions, making it unmaintainable?

Comment: @marmot When I used the minipage, the value I gave for the width didn't seem to matter.  Even when I gave a width that was too small, it still looked fine, but I don't know why.

Comment: @HenriMenke I don't like custom environments/macros because I can't just copy the code and repurpose it later.  I have to remember that there is a custom definition somewhere I have to copy as well.

Comment: @Jeff That's a good observation! (Of course, if you are very picky about `overfull` complaints, you may not want to use it in that way.)

Answer (score 1):

One option is to put it in a minipage and strike this out.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[makeroom]{cancel}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation*}
    \cancel{
        \begin{aligned}
        f(x) &= \sin(x) \\
        g(x) &= \cos(x)
    \end{aligned}
}
\end{equation*}
I want to strikeout this:\\
\xcancel{\begin{minipage}{2cm}~\\[-2\baselineskip]
\begin{flalign*}
    f(x) &= \sin(x) && \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x) &&
\end{flalign*}
\end{minipage}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

The downside of this is that you have to hard code the width of the minipage. You could cure this with a more complicated macro of by using Ti*k*Z.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikznode}[3][]{\tikz[remember
picture,baseline=(#2.base)]{\node(#2)[inner sep=0pt,#1]{#3};}}
\begin{document}
\begin{flalign*}
    \tikznode{lt}{\strut}f(x) &= \sin(x) && \\
    g(x) &= \cos(x)\tikznode{br}{\strut} &&
\end{flalign*}
\tikz[overlay,remember picture]{\draw (lt.north) -- (br.south);}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Yet this might be an overkill.

Comment: I'm not a big fan of `\tikzmark` because unexpected things happen when you have a pagebreak in the middle of your overlay.  The `\cancel{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}}` solution looks sane however.  (Maybe harmonize your indentation)

Comment: @HenriMenke I agree with your concern. Yet I don't understand what you precisely mean by indentation. Note that the `\cancel{\begin{aligned}...\end{aligned}}` is from the OP, and the user uses `flalign`.

Comment: Sorry, I realised that you just copied from OP after I posted the comment.